# Associate two classes for compile-time error

Tags: c#, interface, architecture, abstraction

### So we have two abstract classes:

```
1)Entity
2)TaskEntity
```

### And have impl:

```
1) EntityA, TaskEntityA;
2) EntityB, TaskEntityB;
```

### How can I associate:

- EntityA - TaskEntityA;
- EntityB - TaskEntityB;

### For such purpose:

```
class BaseTaskHandler<TTask> where TTask:TaskEntity
{
    private readonly IEntityRepo<__Some Magic Here or not here, so I can use__> 
}
```

in other words, if TTask is TaskEntityA than injected(or any other way to get instance of) associated 
`IEntityRepo<EntityA>`

If we will use second generic arg it can cause run time error because we can do mistake and write

```
class BaseTaskHandler<TTask,TEntity>
.
.
.
class ATaskHandler:BaseTaskHandler<TaskEntityA, EntityB>
```

So this isn't answer that I search

Comment: I find this stuff much easier to visualise if there is a [mcve] showing an example of `EntityA` and `TaskEntityA`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, so I'll answer to the best of my ability.

With your current implementation, you cannot do what you are asking. If you wish to generically associate the class Entity to the TaskHandler in some class BaseTaskHandler, than that implies that *all* derivations can be associated with one another. This is not an error at all, but how generics are supposed to work. There are three solutions to your problem if you wish to strictly relate strictly EntityA to TaskEntityA and EntityB to TaskEntityB.

YOUR ANSWER ISN'T WRONG

The run-time error you specified may not be an actual error so long as you do not pair the type A with type B. If this truly does cause an error and you don't wish this sort of practice, than you should move on to the following two solutions...

SIMPLEST SOLUTION

Just create two classes for those two entities. If you don't need to use generics and you don't foresee yourself creating new Entities/TaskEntities, then you don't need to abstract your entire application. Just do the following:

```
public class EntityHandlerA
{
    private readonly EntityA _entityA;
    private readonly TaskEntityA _taskEntityA;
    public EntityHandlerA(EntityA ea, TaskEntityA tea)
    {
        _entityA = ea;
        _taskEntityA = tea;
    }
}
public class EntityHandlerB
{
    private readonly EntityB _entityB;
    private readonly TaskEntityB _taskEntityB;
    public EntityHandlerA(EntityB eb, TaskEntityB teb)
    {
        _entityB = ea;
        _taskEntityB = teb;
    }
}
```

GENERIC SOLUTION

If you believe that entities/task entities A and B are truly different, than you need another level of abstraction in your application. Thus if we have A and B inherit from two different base classes BaseEntityA, BaseEntityB, and BaseTaskEntityA and BaseTaskEntityB, you can seperate them logically.

```
// Highest level
public abstract class Entity { }
public abstract class TaskEntity { } 

// Second level of abstractions for entities of type A and B
public abstract class BaseEntityA : Entity { }
public abstract class BaseEntityB : Entity { }
public abstract class BaseTaskEntityA : TaskEntity { }
public abstract class BaseTaskEntityB : TaskEntity { }

// horizontal association of base entites
public class BaseHandlerA<BaseEntityA, BaseTaskEntityA> { }
public class BaseHandlerB<BaseEntityB, BaseTaskEntityB> { }

// implementation of abstractions
public class EntityA : BaseEntityA { }
public class EntityB : BaseEntityB { }
public class TaskEntityA : BaseTaskEntityA { }
public class TaskEntityA : BasTaskEntityB { }
```

And now with these classes, the A types will not be associated with B types in your base handlers. However, this accomplishes the same as the previous solution, so only use this if you feel you must use additional abstraction and that There will be several derivations of BaseEntityA, BaseEntityB, BaseTaskEntityA, and BaseTaskEntityB. If there are no further abstractions, then it may be a waste of time.